# Validation on multiple column not associated with a specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I'm writing an ActiveRecord model and I want to validated the uniqueness of a row based on values in multiple columns. It should look like this:

```
    validates :column_a, {
      uniqueness: {
        scope: [:column_b, :column_c],
      }
    }
```

Here's the thing. It feels awkward. If the validation fails, The ActiveModel attribute will have the `column_a` value and the default rails behaviour would be to start the error message with `column a`. So I guess I it's easy to create a workaround by overriding the default error message but is there a more idiomatic way to approach this?

Comment: No, that's the canonical way to do it.

Comment: It's easy to write a custom validation class, and associate validation failures with the model vs. a particular model attribute. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators